# umlauts (ä, ö, ü) in jquery json autocomplet giving error "403 Forbidden"

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, utf-8

I read several information about that issue and tried the last 2 days to find that error, but unfortunately I wasn't able, so I hope you see it.

The problem is the following: I have a search field where I enter any characters and get a autocompletion dropdown. It is working without issues when I'm not using any special characters. The dropdown is showing the Umlauts correctly, but when I enter "ü" or "ß" or something like that, the Dev Box of Google Chrome browser shows:

"...search.php?term=%C3%BC 403 (Forbidden)"

When I have a look in the "Network" section of Chrome after I entered an Umlaut I see:
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

But when I type a normal character I see:
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8

Without changing any source code. That is strange.

Here is the code I'm using:

HTML/JS:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.autocomplete.css">

 <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(function() {

$("#cityzip").autocomplete({
    source: "http://XXXXXXX/search.php"  ,
    select : function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var value = ui.item.value;
        var sp_value = value.split(' / ');
        var radius = sp_value[0];
        var zip = sp_value[1];
        $('#cityzip').val(ui.item.label);
        $('#addradius').val(radius);
        $('#zip').val(zip);
    },
    focus: function(event, ui) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
  });
});
```

the `search.php`:

```
header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

/*
* database
*/
include 'data.php';  

/*
 * Results array
 */
$results = array();


/*
 * Autocomplete formatter
 */
function autocomplete_format($results) {
    foreach ($results as $result) {
    echo $result[0] . '|' . $result[1] . "\n";
}
}

/*
 * Search for term if it is given
 */

if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
$q = mb_strtolower(($_GET['term']),'UTF-8');
if ($q) {

    foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
        if (strpos(mb_strtolower(($key),'UTF-8'), $q) === 0) {              
            $results[] = array("label" => $key, "value" => $value);
            if(++$i > 6) break;
        }
    }
}
}

/*
 * Output format
 */
$output = 'autocomplete';  
if (isset($_GET['output'])) {
$output = mb_strtolower($_GET['output'],'UTF-8');
}

/*
* Output results
*/
echo json_encode($results);

if (isset($_GET['c'])) {
    echo $data[$_GET['c']];;

}
```

and the database `data.php`:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8");

$data = array(
"Berlin" => "29,4 / 10179",
"Berlin Adlershof" => "2,1 / 12489",
"Berlin Alt - Treptow" => "1,5 / 12435",
"Berlin Altglienicke" => "2,5 / 12524",
"Berlin Französisch - Buchholz" => "3,8 / 12205",
);
?>
```

I'm really grateful for any help. Thank you.

Comment: Are you setting meta tag for HTML page: `<meta charset="utf-8"/>` ? Which DOCTYPE are you using?

Comment: well the file which uses the javascript function is also a php file and just that past is html

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to encode the search term before it is sent, otherwise it won't allow special characters to pass.

```
$encodedTerm = urlencode($_GET['term']);
```